# what causes javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, sslhandshakeexception

I am facing the **javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException** while trying to communicate with server through API.

The issue here is very specific. Only from particular client machine, this exception is happening.

I am using java8. When calling the api, I do not see the api is being hit at the server side and this exception is seen 17 minutes after the api is called. Why is it taking so much time to throw that exception? Is something stopping it from being called?

Then the api is called through the command line using "CURL".. the response is seen, but not through the code. What am I missing here?

There are many other clients who are successfully able to use this service. Why am I seeing this issue only on specific client machine? I have updated the http jars and checked the openssl on the machine is of recent version, so it supports TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2.

openssl is not a problem because from the same machine I am getting the response when hit through the command line. So it means there is no certificate problem, right?

What I am missing here? What are the ways to dig through this?

Edit:
After enabling the debug log with value as ssl below is the failure logged

```
 *** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1507603485 bytes = { 46, 25, 233, 155, 229, 192, 23, 113, 70, 0, 128, 243, 228, 234, 162, 74, 80, 65, 193, 20, 103, 234, 209, 36, 211, 97, 196, 245 }
Session ID:  {6, 123, 53, 216, 50, 219, 185, 178, 236, 232, 9, 154, 213, 12, 174, 171, 131, 30, 8, 105, 18, 70, 74, 35, 157, 100, 145, 53, 206, 33, 38, 9}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 225
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 89
*** ServerHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1948502716 bytes = { 112, 134, 167, 149, 222, 252, 155, 36, 55, 155, 23, 201, 237, 66, 69, 180, 176, 185, 86, 45, 222, 254, 228, 92, 211, 113, 21, 198 }
Session ID:  {6, 123, 53, 216, 50, 219, 185, 178, 236, 232, 9, 154, 213, 12, 174, 171, 131, 30, 8, 105, 18, 70, 74, 35, 157, 100, 145, 53, 206, 33, 38, 9}
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed, ansiX962_compressed_prime, ansiX962_compressed_char2]
***
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
0000: 5A DC 34 1D 2E 19 E9 9B   E5 C0 17 71 46 00 80 F3  Z.4........qF...
0010: E4 EA A2 4A 50 41 C1 14   67 EA D1 24 D3 61 C4 F5  ...JPA..g..$.a..
Server Nonce:
0000: 74 24 CB BC 70 86 A7 95   DE FC 9B 24 37 9B 17 C9  t$..p......$7...
0010: ED 42 45 B4 B0 B9 56 2D   DE FE E4 5C D3 71 15 C6  .BE...V-...\.q..
Master Secret:
0000: 9C 71 48 89 F3 C2 47 A4   08 99 E2 90 10 41 A7 B2  .qH...G......A..
0010: B9 AD E4 94 77 42 2A 03   1B 5A 85 43 48 6A E8 F6  ....wB*..Z.CHj..
0020: 19 AC 45 A7 A7 A1 10 31   AF 47 22 EA 06 08 02 D3  ..E....1.G".....
... no MAC keys used for this cipher
Client write key:
0000: 09 29 08 5C 46 74 F3 F4   25 E8 5E BB 58 F9 B2 87  .).\Ft..%.^.X...
Server write key:
0000: AA 0B 79 6C EE D1 5D 5B   95 24 85 38 66 04 36 BB  ..yl..][.$.8f.6.
Client write IV:
0000: DC FA A6 A3                                        ....
Server write IV:
0000: A5 E7 72 C9                                        ..r.
%% Server resumed [Session-5, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 40
Keep-Alive-Timer, called close()
Keep-Alive-Timer, called closeInternal(true)
Keep-Alive-Timer, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
Keep-Alive-Timer, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 26
Keep-Alive-Timer, called closeSocket(true)
main, received **EOFException**: error
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
%% Invalidated:  [Session-5, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
```

One more find is that my GET requests are getting response after 17 mins but my subsequent POST requests are throwing this EOFException. Any reason?

I went through and searched for the cause of EOFException and I hear the problem with security protocol and the suggestion was to add `System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2");`. I do not see the problem with security protocol in my case because ServerHello and ClientHello are with TLSv1.2.

EDIT 2: Ran openssl s_client sess_out and sess_in commands as suggested by @dave_thompson_085

```
$ openssl s_client -connect 40.dataloader.IRXXX.XXX.com:443 -sess_out tempfile </dev/null
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 C = US, ST = Massachusetts, L = Waltham, O = XXX, OU = IRXXX, CN = IRXXX.XXX.com
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = Massachusetts, L = Waltham, O = XXX, OU = IRXXX, CN = IRXXX.XXX.com
verify error:num=27:certificate not trusted
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = Massachusetts, L = Waltham, O = XXX, OU = IRXXX, CN = IRXXX.XXX.com
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=Massachusetts/L=Waltham/O=XXX/OU=IRXXX/CN=IRXXX.XXX.com
   i:/C=US/O=Symantec Corporation/OU=Symantec Trust Network/CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
XXX
XXX
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=Massachusetts/L=Waltham/O=XXX/OU=IRXXX/CN=IRXXX.XXX.com
issuer=/C=US/O=Symantec Corporation/OU=Symantec Trust Network/CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 2318 bytes and written 421 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID: 850ECBF2236A86B1267114E6F547CA1B52F30EAB36015E1AFAD5FDE5AFCAEA7A
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 382EB56038856142D140479A3A936B1112FC117268039093AFD938D3A710774DD0CE8544B15B6C1FAD13C1A7E5B2FB77
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1524422784
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
---
DONE



$ openssl s_client -connect 40.dataloader.IRXXX.XXX.com:443 -sess_in tempfile
    CONNECTED(00000003)
    depth=0 C = US, ST = Massachusetts, L = Waltham, O = XXX, OU = IRXXX, CN = IRXXX.XXX.com
    verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
    verify return:1
    depth=0 C = US, ST = Massachusetts, L = Waltham, O = XXX, OU = IRXXX, CN = IRXXX.XXX.com
    verify error:num=27:certificate not trusted
    verify return:1
    depth=0 C = US, ST = Massachusetts, L = Waltham, O = XXX, OU = IRXXX, CN = IRXXX.XXX.com
    verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
    verify return:1
    ---
    Certificate chain
     0 s:/C=US/ST=Massachusetts/L=Waltham/O=XXX/OU=IRXXX/CN=IRXXX.XXX.com
       i:/C=US/O=Symantec Corporation/OU=Symantec Trust Network/CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
    ---
    Server certificate
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
    ...
    XXX
    XXX
    ...
    -----END CERTIFICATE-----
    subject=/C=US/ST=Massachusetts/L=Waltham/O=XXX/OU=IRXXX/CN=IRXXX.XXX.com
    issuer=/C=US/O=Symantec Corporation/OU=Symantec Trust Network/CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
    ---
    No client certificate CA names sent
    ---
    SSL handshake has read 2318 bytes and written 453 bytes
    ---
    New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Server public key is 2048 bit
    Secure Renegotiation IS supported
    Compression: NONE
    Expansion: NONE
    SSL-Session:
        Protocol  : TLSv1.2
        Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
        Session-ID: 5DD784DD1BA46EF3251638D4651DB412FC807ECA7CD257CB98C0F1A888859809
        Session-ID-ctx: 
        Master-Key: DC58588177FB5F7192C9972FC705BA070120DB4B1004CA594C1097EDA3DA376E7F8B153BFBFCC1BE557C516E21CCB43D
        Key-Arg   : None
        PSK identity: None
        PSK identity hint: None
        SRP username: None
        Start Time: 1524423133
        Timeout   : 300 (sec)
        Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
    ---
```

Comment: The fact `openssl s_client` succeeds does not establish the server certificate is good because `s_client` is designed as a test tool that ignores (most) certificate errors. But a cert problem wouldn't cause a 17minute delay. As per https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Debug try running with sysprop `javax.net.debug=ssl` to get details of what Java/JSSE is doing and what responses if any it is seeing.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I have just updated the description from captured log by running command with option -Djavax.net.debug=ssl. Please take a look.

Comment: Your client sent the `close_notify`. The server merely responded correctly. It looks like your client timed out the request.

Comment: @EJP: except ServerHello agreeed to a resumption request, so server should have immediately sent CCS and Finished, but client didn't receive them. Deepak: to check this, try `openssl s_client -connect host:port -sess_out tempfile </dev/null` and assuming that completes successfully _immediately_ do `openssl s_client -connect host:port -sess_in tempfile` and see what happens on that second connection (using resumption). Optionally add `-msg` or `-debug` (or in 1.1.0 with compile option `-trace`) for details.

Comment: Ran both the commands accordingly and posted over in the description. when I ran sess_in, it doesn't say "Done" at the end and it didn't return the cursor..

Comment: (You didn't ping me so I just now found this while looking for something else.) Your second `s_client` (with `-sess_in`) didn't have `</dev/null` so after doing successful handshake it is waiting for keyboard input; just type Q return in this situation. More relevant to your problem, the server did not do resumption when openssl requested it -- observe sessionid and masterkey are new -- though it did agree to resumption on the Java request (and then apparently didn't carry it out). I can't explain that (important) difference and thus can't suggest anything further, sorry.